# Lock only specific region of array

Tags: rust

I have read about `std::sync::Mutex` but it lock whole array which I don't want. Mine requirement is lock only region or block (certain contiguous indices) which I'm currently modifying and other regions should be available for other threads for write also.
Can someone give hint for what I should look for?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built into the language. There might be crates for that usecase, though.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if that's even viable, iterating through all locked regions to make sure there is no overlap might be slower than simply locking the entire array.

Comment: You might have to write something yourself if this is absolutely necessary. Although it might be easier to split your array into individually lockable subsections or similar, like `Vec<Mutex<[T; 1024]>>` or similar